# Plugin to delete folder with all of its content

Tags: gulp

I was trying to find a way to delete folder in a gulp - but I couldnt find it. Could you recommend any plugins, that enable deleting?

Thanks!

Comment: [***del***](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md) will help you.

Comment: @The Why not post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***del***](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md) might help you. We use it on our project. It's quite easy to configure and easy to use with gulp. [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) i hope it will help you.